# Pandas - wrong behavior of map function

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have encountered a really strange "bug" when applying a function using `map`.

This is the example `csv` you can use to reproduce the problem:

```
DATE
2017-03-12 02:59:00
2017-03-12 03:59:00
```

The following is the code that I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', parse_dates = ['DATE'])

df['TIMESTAMP_C'] = [str(x.timestamp()) for x in df['DATE']]
df['TIMESTAMP_H'] = df['DATE'].map(datetime.datetime.timestamp).map(str)
```

And the following is the output dataframe:

```
                 DATE   TIMESTAMP_C   TIMESTAMP_H
0 2017-03-12 02:59:00  1489287540.0  1489309140.0
1 2017-03-12 03:59:00  1489291140.0  1489309140.0
```

So, as you can see, the timestamp returned with the map function are the same and not correct. I am wondering why the `list comprehension` returns the correct ones. It may not be a bug and only that I am doing some mistakes with the map function, however, I would really like to use it as it speeds up the computation a lot.

EDIT: I am not asking how to do it, I am asking why the way I am doing it return different results

Comment: I am not really seeing the duplicate. I know how to convert a date in a timestamp, I am asking why is not correct with map @ALollz

Comment: But a bit of an XY problem if you ask me `I would really like to use it as it speeds up the computation a lot`. You're not going to beat the performance of `.astype(int64)/10**9` with that `.map`

Comment: That is true, and I have been also able to test it. Anyway, the title of the question is explicit. `Wrong behavior of map function` not about the datetime conversion. I may have explained it wrong, but it is not the answer to this question. @ALollz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map function is working fine. You are passing an "unbound" method, that belongs to the datetime.datetime class, i.e. `datetime.datetime.timestamp`, and you are passing some `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp` object to it. You shouldn't expect that to work, and I am surprised it isn't throwing an error.

Rather, you want to use the `.timestamp` method of the `pd.TimeStamp` class, so:

```
In [3]: df.DATE.map(pd.Timestamp.timestamp).map(str)
Out[3]:
0    1489287540.0
1    1489291140.0
Name: DATE, dtype: object
```